# Outlook 2010 - Insert text

Tags: c#, outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010 using C#.

From a ribbon button, how do I add text to the top of an email body?

This is what my goal is:
User clicks on New e-Mail, then clicks on a custom ribbon button and the button adds text to the top of the body field

click another button and that same text is removed

Kind of like a mood stamp

Can someone point me in the direction of how to do this?

Comment: I assume you’re on VSTO?

Answer (score 4):

Here’s a quick outline:

- Subscribe to the click event of your ribbon button.
- Get the [`Application.ActiveInspector()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._application.activeinspector.aspx)
- Get its [`Inspector.CurrentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._inspector.currentitem.aspx)
- Attempt to cast it to [`MailItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem.aspx)

  - If the cast fails, assume that it is some other Outlook item type (e.g. contact) and that you shouldn’t do anything with it
- Read the mail item’s [`BodyFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.bodyformat.aspx)
- Depending on the format, you will need to alter [`Body`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.body.aspx), [`RTFBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.rtfbody.aspx), or [`HTMLBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.htmlbody.aspx)

  - The first one, representing the plain-text body, is trivial; you just prepend your text to it:
    `mailItem.Body = "My text\r\n" + mailItem.Body;`
  - The other two will require you to take care of formatting syntax

Comment: this worked out great, however I have one more question about it. Is there a way to make it so that the user is not able to edit the value?

Comment: Probably not by altering the body. Maybe you could prepend your text _after_ the user clicks "Send"?